# How to exclude rows against multiple filter criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet where I don't want to see any rows that contain either a `"+"` or a `"["` in a certain column... Can't figure out how to do that.

The built-in Filter function only lets me add one condition from what I can see, and regex match is just saying "true" or "false" (for some reason I thought it would spit out data that matched... guess not).

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what I ended up going with:

```
=query(B:B, "select *
where
not B contains '-'
and not B contains '+'
and not B contains '""'
and not B contains '['")
```

!

But I'm guessing there is a more succinct way of achieving this...?

Comment: HAve you tried using the regex in your query?  I am =query(B:B, "Select * where A matches '.*/[A-Z,0-9]+/.*' ")  I am sure you need more but I am guessing you have the regex already worked out.  I have that only as an example.